# will $x_{n+1}=x_n/2$ if $x_n$ is even; otherwise $x_{n+1}=3*x_n+1$, will $x_n$ shrink to 1?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, open-problem

I was asked this question that, for any $x_1 \in \mathbb{N}$, define the sequence as

$$x_{n+1}=\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
     x_n/2 & \quad \text{if } x \text{ is even} \\
    3 x_n+1 & \quad \text{if } x \text{ is odd}
  \end{array} \right.$$

Will $x_n$ always shrink to 1?

ps. My knowledge on Number theory is really close to $0$. I'm not sure if this is an elementary or advanced question.

Comment: This is the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), and is very open.

Comment: This would be a very advanced question in terms of how difficult it is to solve! Consider that Erdos (a great mathematician) famously stated: "mathematics is not yet ready for such problems"! For more, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CollatzProblem.html.

Comment: @T.Bongers thanks, i got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to close my question. it's actually answered in the comments.